# Sequelize validation using regular expression

Tags: node.js, regex, postgresql, validation, sequelize.js

I'm trying to use Regular expression in User Model to validate the password field. But it doesn't work for some reason. I've checked the sequelize docs and it says the validations should run automatically on `create`, `update` and `save`. [Link to Docs on validation.](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/models-definition.html#validations)

I have tried using `is` and a custom validator `checkPassword`. Both are not returning any error. Can someone please explain what am I doing wrong here?

Here's is the my user model

```js
import { CustomError } from '../../utils/error';

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define(
    'User',
    {
      firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
      lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
      email: {
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        validate: {
          isEmail: true
        }
      },
      password: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        validate: {
          checkPassword(value) {
            if (
              !/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[#$^+=!*()@%&]).{8,}$/.test(
                value
              )
            ) {
              throw new CustomError(400, 'Provide a valid password!');
            }
          },

          is: {
            args: /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[#$^+=!*()@%&]).{8,}$/,
            msg:
              'The password must contain atleast 8 characters including at least 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase and one digit.'
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {}
  );
  User.associate = function(models) {
    User.hasMany(models.Post, {
      foreignKeyConstraint: true,
      foreignKey: 'userId'
    });
    User.hasMany(models.Comment, {
      foreignKey: 'userId',
      foreignKeyConstraint: true
    });
  };
  return User;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use below method to validate  a password

```
validate: {
      validatePassword: function(password) {
                    if(!(/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,12}$/.test(password))) {
                        throw new Error('The password must contain at least 10 and maximum 12 characters including at least 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase, one number and one special character.');
                    }
                }
            },
```

And here is a different regular expression for passwords string check

1. Minimum ten characters, at least one letter and one number:

> "^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{10,}$"

2. Minimum ten characters, at least one letter, one number and one special character:

> "^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*#?&]{10,}$"

3. Minimum 10 characters, at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter and one number:

> "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{10,}$"

4. Minimum 10 characters, at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number and one special character:

> "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{10,}$"

5. Minimum 10 and maximum 12 characters, at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number and one special character:

> "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{10,12}$"

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. The reason the validation wasn't working was because I was already hashing the password so it was passing the validation rules. Now I have moved the validation to where I'm taking the password from the user.